# Extract all images and text from Clipboard in Java

Tags: java, image, clipboard, toolkit

If I open a browser and copy all of the page's text and images (CTRL+A), and then paste into Microsoft Word for example, both the text and images will be pasted.

I'm trying to write Java code that extracts the text and all the images from the clipboard contents in order to use the text/images within the program, such as displaying the image in a GUI later with supporting text.

Right now my code successfully extracts text from clipboard contents containing both text and images, but the image portion fails. The image code only works if the clipboard content contains a single image (such as pressing Print Screen). Otherwise it says:

`java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: Image
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.getData(SunClipboard.java:220)
    at Filter.main(Filter.java:28)`

How do I alter this code so that text is stored in a String variable, and all images are stored in an image array? Anything helps, thanks.

```
public class Filter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();

        String result;
        try {
            result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {}

        try {
            BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\image.jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
        }
        //getData throws this.
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
            ufe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is supported but you can take a look by examining the return of `public DataFlavor[] getAvailableDataFlavors()`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not certain I understand, but I tried this: 
            `DataFlavor[] getAvailableDataFlavors = new DataFlavor[]{};
            System.out.println(clipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors());` which printed out `[Ljava.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;@446cdf90` Not sure what I'm suppose to expect..

Comment: @JimJim It's an array, you should iterate over it and print each individual `DataFlavor`, this is telling you the different ways in which the contents of the clipboard can be extracted

Comment: Are you saying the clipboard content is an array? Does this mean that if I copy a different website's contents then it may not be available in array format? I'm looking for a dynamic solution. Thanks for your suggestion below, I'll check it out

Comment: @JimJim No, I'm saying the contents can be read in different ways, depending on what you need, you would use a different `DataFlavor` to get access to the content in a particular format (`String`, `Image`, `Reader`, what ever the clipboard is capable of providing based on the available `DataFlavor`s)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I alter this code so that text is stored in a String variable, and all images are stored in an image array? Anything helps, thanks.

You don't.  You inspect the contents of clipboard for the best way to retrieve it, for example..

Selecting all the contents of a web page and copying it, then running...

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
for (DataFlavor flavor : clipboard.getAvailableDataFlavors()) {
    System.out.println(flavor);
}
```

produces..

```
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-text-encoding;representationclass=[B]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/html;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=application/x-java-serialized-object;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.Reader]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.lang.String]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.CharBuffer]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[C]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=unicode]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-8]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16BE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=UTF-16LE]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=ISO-8859-1]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.io.InputStream;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=java.nio.ByteBuffer;charset=US-ASCII]
java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[mimetype=text/plain;representationclass=[B;charset=US-ASCII]
```

Now, you need to pick one which will be most useful to you, maybe something like...

```
try {
    Object data = clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.allHtmlFlavor);
    System.out.println(data);
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which just happens to return a `String` representation of the html/text content, because, lets face it, that's all a web page actually is.

You'll need to parse the page for appropriate resources and download them manually

Comment: One thing here is that not all browsers on all platforms/JDK implementations will match to a sane DataFlavor. For instance, Safari on OS X gives plain and rtf but not html.

Comment: @pvg That's true, that's why you need to have the ability to fall back onto the available data flavors, this is just an example of providing the means to do diagnostics for the problem and find appropriate mechanisms which will support your goal. A simpler solution might be to read the html directly

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I tried your suggestion and it successfully retrieves the html (with image URLs included). However, I'm confused when you say I must download the resources manually. How is it possible for Microsoft Word to allow a user to simply paste in a site's contents and have the images simply appear? Is it manually downloading each image in the background? I'm assuming by "manually" you mean writing Java code to download each individual image (resource) and *not* that I personally have to right-click > save each image. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Microsoft Word parses the HTML just a a web browser (remember you can generate HTML from Word), so it downloads all the images itself and layouts out the content as it might appear in a browser.  Yes, when I say manually, you will need to parse the HTML (maybe with jsoup), finding all the elements you are interested (text/images) and download the resources you want yourself.  The clipboard is only giving you the  text/html content, nothing more

Comment: Cool, makes sense. I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I've successfully used jsoup to create an `ArrayList` of the image URLs from the clipboard contents. Your previous comment said I must "download the resources I want". Does this mean I have to save each image to disk, in order to use it in my java program? I want users to be able to paste text into a field in my app, which will then parse out the images and display the first one within the app. If they click next, it will display the next image. Is saving to disk the best way or is there some sort of internal means of saving/retrieving images within the java app itself? Thanks!

Comment: You have two choices, you can download the image from the URLs, which will load them into memory or you can download the images locally to disk and reuse them. Which you use will depend on how fast you want to reload the images

Comment: In terms of speed, once the user pastes data into the text field I'd like the first image in the array to appear almost instantly. If they click "next", it should load the next image almost instantly. Is local file or memory ideal for this? If memory is best, can you recommend which java terms to learn about, such as `BufferedImage` or something? I'll figure it out from there. Appreciated

Comment: Downloading the image to disk and then loading as apposed to loading it directly into memory probably doesn't have that much difference in initial time difference, you still need to download the image from the web.  If you use the `ImageIO` library, you could actually accomplish both by using `ImageIO.read(URL)` and `ImageIO.write(...)`, so the read would download the image, making it available as a `BufferedImage`, and write would allow you to cache it, meaning that should you need to reload it (later), you can do so from disk, which would be much quicker