# How to return the value copied in Java?

Tags: java

I have a program in java in which I use Robot and with the robot I select a link of a web, and I need to extract from my code that copied link.

```
public void copyCtrlC() {
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
}
```

And I immediately extract the value with:

```
public String getClipboard()
{
    // Obtenemos el contenido del portapapeles del sistema.
    Clipboard portapapeles=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable datos=portapapeles.getContents(null);

      if(datos.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)){

        try
        {
            return (String) ((Clipboard) datos).getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
        // Si lo copiado no es un texto, devolvemos null
        return null;
}
```

And that return returns me an empty value, but when I debug I can do a ctrl+v and if it returns me the value I have copied

**EDITED**

Validate by first copying a data with

```
public void copy() {
     this.vpn = "copy";
     StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(this.vpn);
     clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
}
```

After that I use the method  `copyCtrlC()` with the same link of a page and try to extract the value with `getClipboard()`

And it gives me back the value of 'copy' which is the value I had copied first and not the link

Comment: Check what data flavours are actually support, `stringFlavor` might not be supported

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170527/extract-all-images-and-text-from-clipboard-in-java/34170633#34170633)